# How to make a circular background fill its container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a circular background color that completely fills its container in Flutter. My desired result looks like this:

[image: desired result]

Currently, my code produces this:

[image: current result]

**Here's my code:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(

          decoration:  BoxDecoration
            (color:  Color(0xffF24004),

          ),
          child: Container(
            width: 202,
            height: 196,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle, color : Color(0xffF2B749),

              )),

        ),
      ),

    );

  }
}
```

I've tried using `BoxFit.cover` but it hasn't solved the issue. How can I achieve the desired circular background effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give backgroundcolor to the Scaffold as well. Try out this below code.

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 202,
          height: 196,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Color(0xffF2B749),
          ),
        ),
        // Add Another Icon Here
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Center` widget, you can also set the background color of the `Scaffold` directly

You can also use a Column right under the scaffold and set main, and cross axis alignments to center

But to achieve the design you posted you should probably use a `Stack` widget, coupled with `Positioned` widgets

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 202,
        height: 196,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Color(0xffF2B749),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give backgroundColor to Scaffold only:-

```
backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004)
```